# How to show UTF-8 encoded languages in ATG Commerce?

Tags: java, utf-8, localization, internationalization, atg

We are trying to internationalize a ATG commerce site(made over CRS). The site supports 2 locals.. en_th and th_th. We have added the th(thailand) translation in products using BCC as shown below.
[image]

Now when we display this product details in a JSP, the english version comes properly but the thailand version of the same comes in "??????????????????????"

Configurations I have done so far:

1. Added UTF-8 support in server.xml in Jboss
2. JSP has UTF-8 support and on rendering using browser the source code
   shows UTF-8
3. Added

   ```
   pResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
           pResponse.setContentType("text/html"); this in my droplet also to be on safe side.
   ```

What else needs to be done? any clue?

Comment: What is the character set of your databse? I believe the default Oracle character set is ISO 8859-1 (WE8ISO8859P1 in Oracle terms) and this would not support characters used by languages in the far east. Use UTF8 instead.

Comment: ^^ Ya right, that was the problem and changing it for all existing tables/columns is a huge ask when the database is in GBs and tables in 1000's. Any suggestion on this regard would be great..

Comment: My suggestion would be to have an expert DBA join the team and manage the process. I wouldn't attempt a data migration based on advice from any forum (regardless of how good it might be).

Comment: Ya thats right chrisjileu. Thats the plan. Thanks for the help and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the content type in an HTML tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also, make sure the doctype is declared at the top of the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set also one of the following
In your JSP set this in the header section

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

and/or

```
pResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Hope this help

Comment: That I have tried already as #2. The thing is even when I debug in my droplet I dont see the character comming properly. I have changed settings in eclipse to support utf-8 but no use.